# google cloud compute engine letsencrypt problems

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, google-compute-engine, lets-encrypt

I have a server on Compute Engine (Google Cloud) Centos 7, ISConfig, no more than 20 domains, some subdomains, using letsencrypt for SSL.
Sometimes letsencrypt connections fail with timeout. On detailed review I think is a DNS issue because there are differences resolving acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org from different machines or networks.
Forcing (edit /etc/hosts) another known IP LetsEncrypt Works fine, no more timeouts for some days.

Someone resolve this issue with a best option ?
Thanks

Anytime I detect problems, I edit /etc/hosts to update resolve acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org

Answer (score 0):

What is says in `/var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log` ?

What is shown in [Stackdriver](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=%3CYOUR_PROJECT_ID%3E&resource=gce_instance%2Finstance_id%25%3CINSTANCE_ID_NUMBER%3E) filtering by the Compute Engine name ?

Did you try to `install apt-get install python-certbot-nginx` ? (if you use Nginx :0) and google it for more details)

Comment: 1.- log register TimeOut
2.- works using custom /etc/hosts
3.- I use Centos and Apache, but this is not a problem, package versions are ok